# UPDATED: Applying AJAX'd JSON data to existing checkboxes and checking/unchecking (jQuery)

Tags: javascript, jquery, coldfusion

This question has been cleaned up and isn't so wordy as it was. Hope it helps.

web stack: ColdFusion 12+/Lucee 5.x
db: mySQL/Maria
handlebars are also in play here though I don't think has any relevance for this question.

I have a form with three sections:
The first section is a series of checkboxes
The second section is a series of radio buttons
The third section is another set of checkboxes

When some checkboxes in the first section are checked AND a radio button is selected, an ajax call is made to the database to retrieve "active" values for checkboxes that correspond to the checkboxes in the third section. The entire list of checkboxes in the third section should always be visible because the user can make additional selections/deselections as needed.

Hopefully this example will help:

**Section One**

```
CHECKBOX 1 [X]      CHECKBOX 2 [ ]      CHECKBOX 3 [ ]      CHECKBOX 4 [X]
```

**Section Two**

```
RADIO 20 ( )      RADIO 21 ( )      RADIO 22 (*)      RADIO 23 ( )      RADIO 24 ( )
```

So based upon the options selected above, the following would be presented to the user but the user can still change as needed.
**Section Three**

```
CHECKBOX 101 [X]      CHECKBOX 102 [ ]      CHECKBOX 103 [ ]      CHECKBOX 104 [ ]      CHECKBOX 105 [x]      CHECKBOX 106 [X]
```

I don't have code to share yet as I'm just getting started on this area of the application but if someone would be willing to work with me on this, I can post code (and/or gist) as I go along. I suspect this SO question will take some time before I will be able to mark an answer as correct so just know that going forward. I think this will be a fun exercise though and I look forward to the feedback.

**=============TO GIVE SCENARIO SOME CONTEXT=============**
Let's say this is am "ideal mate personality profile" (it's not but let's pretend here). Using the example layout provided above, Section 1 has 4 checkboxes of physical attributes (hair color, eye color, build, etc.). Then section 2 is the education completed (how smart do you want your ideal mate to be). As the developer, I make the assumption that if the user selects from Section 1 the checkboxes for 1 and 4 and then in Section 2 the radio option of Radio 22 (Smart), then that they will probably select Checkboxe 101, 105, and 106 (determined, witty, and conversationalist) so I'd like to check those options off for them as a convenience. If the user changes their selection in Section 2 from Radio 22 (Smart) to Radio 24 (Off of the Chart Smart), then the items in Section 3 that are checked off will change to matched the predetermined mapping.

The database has two tables of data - the source data that shows the options for the checkboxes/radio options and then a 2nd table that shows the mapping (see image below).
[image: mapping example of how the data is currently stored]

**My question essentially is** How can I apply the mapped values to the data already loaded on the page? In psuedo code:
 - retrieve JSON mapping data values
 - loop over the DOM elements comparing the existing item to the value returned from the ajax call
 - if it matches, check the box
 - if it does not match, leave the box as it was in case the user selected the checkbox

Comment: question is not clear.Can you brief what exactly the question is

Comment: @brk Thank you for commenting. I updated the question. If you scroll to the bottom part, I think this may be a better description of my question.

Comment: Well that was TONS easier than I thought. I just looped over the elements with an name and checked if it was checked or not. If it wasn't, I added the check. I'll post the answer once I have code. When I added more details (aka psuedo code), the solution literally there before me.

Comment: Yep, writing out the psuedo code of a problem, first, often leads you to the solution!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nothing fancy here, just take the returned data and apply it to the existing data and check it. Easy peasy.

Note: This isn't verbatim from my implementation and is not copy & paste worthy; however, it answered my question sufficient enough for government work.

```
var formData = $("#myRighteousForm :not(.exclude)").serialize();
$.ajax({
    method: "POST",
    url: "/?action=card.getData",
    dataType: "JSON",
    data: formData   
}).then(
    function(response) {
        $.each(response.data, function(key, value) {
            $('#id_' + value.thisLabel + ':checkbox').prop('checked', true); 
        });
    }
);
```